# Convert worldcoordinates to screen coordinates

Tags: vector, 3d, 2d, projection

How can I convert a 3D vector into a 2D vector that can be drawn on screen?
I have the camera position, the positon of the 3D point, the vertical and horizontal rotation of the camera, the screen resolution and the field of view.
I heard about the world to screen function but do not know how to use it. Is there a way to do it just using maths?

Thx. in advance.

Answer (score 0):

mate. Your question is not of simple answer. I would explain the maths to you if I remembered. But it's been some time since I don't study linear algebra.

First, the methods you would call to do that uses the math you are looking for, and it is probably optimized!

But, regarding your questions about the maths behind it, here is a link:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection

This "3d vector to 2D vector screen point" is called projection, and you are probably referring to perspective projection. It is explained in the link.

If you are interested in learning it, you should first study some linear algebra, and then start studying computer graphics. (One good book: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0321399528/ref=as_li_qf_sp_asin_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=9325&creativeASIN=0321399528&linkCode=as2&tag=casueffe06-20](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321399528))